# How do I configure a decorator with Castle Windsor?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, decorator

I have a decorator and actual implementation that looks like this:

```
public interface IAmUsedTwice
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class ForReal: IAmUsedTwice
{
    public SomethingElse Need { get; set; }

    public ForReal(SomethingElse iNeed)
    {
        Need = iNeed;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Realing doing something here");
    }
}

public class SomethingElse {}

public class DecoratingIsFun: IAmUsedTwice
{
    private IAmUsedTwice Actual { get; set; }

    public DecoratingIsFun(IAmUsedTwice actual)
    {
        Actual = actual;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a decorator!");
        Actual.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

and the configuration was set up before I started this using xml for the actual implementation and looks something like this:

```
<component id="forReal"
           service="SomeNamespace.IAmUsedTwice, SomeNamespace"
           type="SomeNamespace.ForReal, SomeNamespace">
  <parameters>
    <iNeed>${iNeed}</iNeed>        
  </parameters>
</component>
```

and you can assume that the iNeed component is set up correctly already.

Now, the system is already configured to use the ForReal class, but what I want to do is swap out the ForReal class and use the DecoratingIsFun class now.

I created an installer to register the DecoratingIsFun class like so:

```
public class DecoratorInstaller: IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IAmUsedTwice>()
                .ImplementedBy<DecoratingIsFun>()
        );
    }
}
```

However, I still need to tell it two things.

1. When it resolves IAmUsedTwice I want it to resolve an instance of DecoratingIsFun from now on instead of the other class
2. When resolving DecoratingIsFun I need it to resolve ForReal as a constructor argument for the instance it's creating.

The goal will be that I can then call windsorContainer.Resolve() and get a DecoratingIsFun instance.

How can I tell the installer to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow `DecoratingIsFun` to decorate `ForReal`, you need to ensure that `DecoratingIsFun` is registered *before* `ForReal` - then Windsor will correctly resolve the decorator and satisfy its dependency with the next registration of something that implements `IAmUsedTwice`.

But since you're using XML to register the first service, I don't know how to achieve that, since the XML is sucked up when you instantiate `WindsorContainer`.

But why are you using XML in the first place? Is it because you don't think that you can use XML to *configure* components unless you're also using it to *register* them?

If that is the case, you should reduce the XML to something like this:

```
<component id="forReal">
    <parameters>
        <iNeed>${iNeed}</iNeed>        
    </parameters>
</component>
```

and move the registration to your code, allowing you to control the order of registration. Then, make sure that `ForReal` is registered with `.Named("forReal")`, allowing the configuration to be matched when the instance is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The reason I'm using XML is because the XML actually from legacy code, so it's been kind of my "starting point".  However, I'd like to start migrating things over to the Fluent API, hence having part of it in the XML and part in the Fluent API.